# Programmatically forming a sentence from a list of nouns

Tags: algorithm, nlp, information-retrieval, linguistics

I have a requirement in which I am given a set of nouns and I have to programmatically phrase (form) a sentence from those nouns.

As an example -
 
Suppose, I am given a set of nouns like - 
**{"chocolate", "candy", "sugar", "milk"}**, 
I have to programmatically phrase a sentence like - 
"This is a **chocolate candy** made of **sugar** and **milk**".
The sentence can be anything but it should contain the given nouns and it should be meaningful.
I tried researching on Ontologies to see if it can help. I looked at WordNet to get more information about each noun and try to phrase the sentence. I am not getting any other better approach to do so. I am very new to NLP and making my way through.
How can I programmatically achieve something of this sort?
Is there any algorithm that I can make use of?
Please suggest.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Do you need a meaning full sentence, or just a grammatically valid one?

Comment: I think you also need lists of articles (a, an, the), verbs, adverbs, adjectives and prepositional phrases. The basic sentence structure is [Art adj noun verb adv pp], so for example, A green dog ran slowly down the street. Once you have lists of all those you can randomly pick one word from each list to construct a sentence. If you have to use multiple nouns then you can have 1 subject noun and multiple prepositional phrases.

Comment: @Elyashiv - It should be a meaningful sentence. We can take a step by step approach with first step being grammatically correct one's. Step two will be to build on step one and get a meaningful sentence.

Comment: @Joseph James - Unfortunately, I just have a list of nouns and nothing else. Like we try to extract entities from a sentence, we have to reverse the process of constructing the sentence from the entities.
But that's a great input to choose one subject noun and multiple prepositional phrases.

Comment: **Semantic Association** and **Concept Net** [link](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki) seems to be a great starting point. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 5):

**Semantic Association** and **Concept Net** seems to be a great starting point. The link for ConceptNet can be found here ([link](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet5/wiki)).

ConceptNet is a multilingual knowledge base, representing words and phrases that people use and the common-sense relationships between them.

It is basically a graph structure with each node representing an entity (in our case noun) and the edge between the nodes represent the relationship.

This is the API to get the graph for chocolate in ConceptNet - [link](http://conceptnet5.media.mit.edu/data/5.4/c/en/chocolate)

According to this we can form the sentence like - 
"Chocolate is a candy and is sweet made from milk solids and sugar and vanilla"